# Passing List<Class> from one Activity to another Activity

Tags: android, json

How to pass list of class i.e(List) from one activity to another.
  For example i have the following json:-

```
{
"acclst":[{
    "accountInfoData":[{
            "userId":9,
            "rid":"1-Z5S3",
            "acnme":"acc_1234.",
            "actpe":"Fabricator / Distributor",
            "mph":"2660016354",
            "euse":"Biofuels",
            "com":"0",
            "sta":"Active",
            "stem":"BBUSER5",
            "wsite":"",
            "fax":"",
            "zone":"",
            "crted":"BBUSER4",
            "statusX":1,
            "partyId":0,
            "address":[]
        }
    ]
}
],
"conlst":[],
"actlst":[],
"prolst":[],
"code":"200"
}
```

So how how to pass the conlst from one activity to another?Any examples would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add List in Bundle and put bundle in Intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this,nextActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key",conlst );  
i.putExtras(packData);
startActivity(i);
```

Otherwise make your Class from List parcelable | http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html and put them in bundle like this -

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("key",conlst );    
i.putExtras(packData);
startActivity(i);
```